# Inquiry: Loops in Relation to Parent - Child - Fork - Pids

Tags: perl, loops, fork, parent-child

I am attempting to learn the functionality of parents, children and pipes in perl. My goal is to create a single pipe (not bidirectional) that reads from the command line, and prints it through a pipe. Referencing the pids many many times.

The code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;
use strict;


pipe(READPIPE, WRITEPIPE);
WRITEPIPE->autoflush(1);
STDOUT->autoflush(1);

my $parentpid = $$;
my $childpid = fork() // die "Fork Failed $!\n";

# This is the parent
if ($childpid) {  
    &parent ($childpid);
    close READPIPE;
    close WRITEPIPE;
    waitpid ($childpid,0);
    print "Parent: The child pid with a pid of: $childpid as stopped, and the parent with the pid: $parentpid has stopped.\n";
    exit;
}
# This is the child
elsif (defined $childpid) {
    &child ($parentpid);
    close WRITEPIPE;

}

else {}

sub parent { 
    while(1){
        my $input = <STDIN>;
        if ($input eq "\n"){print "Undef- CRTL+C = Quit\n", last;}
        else {
            print "ParentSub: The parent pid is: ",$parentpid, " and the message being received is: ", $input;
            print WRITEPIPE "$input";
            print "ParentSub: My parent pid is: $parentpid\n";
            print "ParentSub: My child pid is: $childpid\n";    
             }
        }
}

sub child {
    while ($line = <READPIPE>){
        print "ChildSub: The child pid is: " $childpid,"\n";
        print "ChildSub: I got this line from the pipe: ",$line," and the child pid is ",$childpid,"\n";
                              }
}
```

Current output is:

```
Hello World
ParentSub: The parent pid is: 2633 and the message being received is:  Hello World
ParentSub: My parent pid is: 2633
ParentSub: My child pid is: 2634
ChildSub: The child pid is: 0
ChildSub: I got this line from the pipe: Hello World
, and the child pid is 0
```

I am running into a few issues that I don't quite understand.

1. It does not exit the loop properly- it exits but continues on with no context (there a 4 blank lines after the bottom of the output from hitting the enter key (aka "\n")- it doesn't proceed to the     `print "parent: the child pid with ......exit;`
2. When I add a line in before the `<STDIN>` ex. `print "Enter something here: "`
   it doesn't repeat that line as part of the loop- making readability not flush.

Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is with closing the pipe ends. The direct error is about `WRITEPIPE`.

All pipes' ends *must be closed in all processes* that see them. Otherwise something may be left waiting on a pipe which the other end forgot about. From [Avoiding pipe deadlocks in perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Avoiding-Pipe-Deadlocks)

> Whenever you have more than one subprocess, you must be careful that each closes whichever half of any pipes created for interprocess communication it is not using. This is because any child process reading from the pipe and expecting an EOF will never receive it, and therefore never exit. A single process closing a pipe is not enough to close it; the last process with the pipe open must close it for it to read EOF.

In this case the child closes `WRITEPIPE` only *after* it reads (what *parent* writes), so the parent doesn't have the EOF on its `WRITEPIPE` when needed and thus never quits it.  You need `Ctrl+C` to stop. Simply moving `close WRITEPIPE` before `child(...)` gets the program to work as intended.

It is also striking that the child never closes `READPIPE` (and never exits).

There are other issues, some of stylistic nature, and a few compilation errors. Here is a working program, with as little change as feasible, with same names and simplified prints

```
use warnings;
use strict;
#use IO::Handle;  # need this on pre-v5.14 (?) versions for autoflush

pipe (my $readpipe, my $writepipe);

$writepipe->autoflush(1);
STDOUT->autoflush(1);

my $parentpid = $$; 
my $childpid = fork() // die "Fork failed $!\n";

# This is the child
if ($childpid == 0) {
    close $writepipe;  # child reads
    child ($parentpid);
    close $readpipe;
    exit;
}
# This is the parent
close $readpipe;       # parent writes
parent ($childpid);
close $writepipe;
waitpid $childpid, 0; 
print "Parent: child $childpid exited, parent $parentpid done.\n";

sub parent { 
    while (1) {
        my $input = <STDIN>;
        if ($input eq "\n") { print "Undef- CRTL+C = Quit\n", last; }
        else {
            print "ParentSub: parent $parentpid got the message: ", $input;
            print $writepipe "$input";
            print "ParentSub: parent pid is $parentpid\n";
            print "ParentSub: child pid is  $childpid\n";        
        }   
    }   
}

sub child {
    while (my $line = <$readpipe>) {
        print "ChildSub: child pid is $childpid\n";
        print "ChildSub: got from the pipe: $line";
    }   
}
```

Prints

```
hello  [Entered at STDIN]
ParentSub: parent 22756 got the message: hello
ParentSub: parent pid is 22756
ParentSub: child pid is  22757
ChildSub: child pid is 0
ChildSub: got from the pipe: hello

Parent: child 22757 exited, parent 22756 done.  [After Enter at STDIN]
```

Note: the message in `if ($input eq "\n")` is only good for the next run, since you also have `last` there, to quit `STDIN` on emtpy line. Usage messages belong on top, when the show starts.

I've simplified prints to be more readable.  Copy yours back if you don't like these.

Comments

- Aways *first* close the unneeded end of pipe in each process
- Use lexical filehandles, they are better (`my $reader` instead of `READER` etc)
- No need to test `defined` on child since you nicely used defined-or (`//`) at `fork`
- The one needed test is normally for child, `if ($pid == 0)`
- The child normally `exit`s, so only the parent process remains after the child's block
- With any writes/reads between processes you want to handle `SIGPIPE`. See docs below
- You need to check exit status, errors, etc.  See docs below.

Documentation: [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html), [fork](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html) and [exec](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html), [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)  (on `$?`, `$!`, and `%SIG`), [pipe](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pipe.html) *and links*.

It is compulsory to carefully go through many parts of [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) (along with other docs).

Comment: Incredible information.  Prior to reading this I had finished the program with assistance of the person teaching me- but unbelievable how much information and understanding I gained from your answer.

Comment: @The_Makings_Of_A_Coder Thank you for the kind words, glad it helps :).  Make sure to work through the docs, to carefully assemble good knowledge. This is complex, and a bit tricky. Good luck and have fun :)