# Detecting the end of a Pipe in Perl

Tags: perl, pipe, eof

I'm trying to fork a separate process/thread in perl and get the input back to the parent via a pipe. For instance:

```
my($RD, $WR);
pipe($RD, $WR);

if(fork()) 
{
   #parent
   while(!eof $RD) { print "From Child: " . readline($RD); }
   print "Parent reached EOF\n";
} else {
   #child
   for(my $i = 0; $i < 25; $i++) { print $WR "$i\n"; }
   close $WR;
}
```

All of the lines from the child are recieved and printed out by the parent. But the parent never detects EOF and is stuck in that while loop, waiting. What is the proper way to detect EOF here?

Comment: It's a process you are forking (not a thread).  You have a full answer by ikegami, but you may want to also look over [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42639033/4653379), with some eerily similar issues and points.

Comment: Well - that depends upon the OS. If you are on a unix/linux type OS, then yes its a new process. On Windows, where I'm working, you don't get a true new process. You get a simulated new process which is really a thread.

Comment: Ah, a good point. Didn't think of Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file handle is only closed when all file descriptors referring to that handle are closed. Have the parent close its copy.

```
pipe(my ($RD, $WR))
   or die("pipe: $!\n");

defined( my $pid = fork() )
   or die("fork: $!\n");

if ($pid) {
   # parent
   close($WR);

   print "From Child: $_" while <$RD>;
   print "Parent reached EOF\n";
} else {
   # child
   close($RD);

   print $WR "$_\n" for 0..25;
}
```

Comment: Ah, didn't realize there was referencing counting going on behind the scenes. Works like a charm - thanks!